# Inserting text in GtkTextBuffer from files

Tags: c, gtk

I am trying to create a GtkNotebook where each page displays information after the program has run out. I don't wish to edit it and just want that it displays itself.

The trouble is that gtk_text_buffer_insert () asks for a const gchar string . I have been storing all the information to be displayed in the files.

How can I insert the string from the files.

Is there a better widget suited for my need that just displays the information on to the page of the notebook.

Thanks a lot ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take it these are log files from the program? Your two choices would seem to be either to remember (in memory) the data you wrote to them, so you can also display it in the GtkNotebook, or to reopen the log files to read them.

Comment: They are the log files but could you tell how to do that.... as in I how can I read the data from file to the Gtextbuffer??

Comment: @user506710: You will read them into a (g)char* (C string), and then add them to the GtkTextBuffer. Reading data from files is generally done using functions from stdio.h; there are [many examples](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[c]+read+text+from+file) on SO. The exact method of course depends on the file format and desired read format.